# I have a desktop with USB ports that have never been active

Tags: usb

- I have a LG desktop computer that was given to me.  I've had issues
  with the USB ports from the beginning. The ports on the top/front did
  not work, I found a cable in the case that had not been plugged in
  which activated two-3.0 blue ports.  On the back I have 2 active blue
  ports.  I also have, not working, 4 black and 5 red. I have Logitech
  keyboard and mouse using two-3.0 ports on the back and external
  speakers using one 3.0 port on the top/front.

```
lsusb 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 008 Device 004: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver 
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser 
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, lost the line feeds.

Comment: What are blue ports? What are the black and red you talk about?

Comment: the blue ports are 3.0, the black are the 2.0. Red, according to my search, is 3.2.  If that is your question.

Comment: You may want to add that info to the question,